# How to detect crawler traffic on my Nodejs server

Tags: node.js, express, traffic

i have developed Nodejs express server and i am concern about the crawler traffic ....i mean if somebody starts sending request to my server to make it down, then how to detect or avoid that.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/isbot

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell what you're really asking here.

If what you're really asking is how you can identify a crawler when they make a request of your site, then all well-behaved crawlers (such as those from Google) will identify themselves in the request.  You can see how Google crawlers do it [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en).

If what you're really asking is how can you defend your server against a situation where you get too much traffic at once and some of that traffic is from crawlers, then that is a very broad question and would require tons of information about your specific server instance, what scale it currently supports, etc...  Here's one article on the general topic: [Web Crawlers: Love the Good, but Kill the Bad and the Ugly](http://www.blogtips.org/web-crawlers-love-the-good-but-kill-the-bad-and-the-ugly/).

For Google, you can actually tell it what the max crawl rate on your site should be.  See this Google page titled ["Change Googlebot crawl rate"](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/48620) for instructions, though this setting only stays in force for 90 days so it's most useful when you first add a ton of new content to your site that a crawler will want to see.

Note: You call also implement a [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) file to instruct crawlers what parts of your site to avoid.